# What IPv6 Should I use

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have multiple IPv6s I need to know what works, on my network they all work, but I need to know what to use for my AAAA record.
`ip address`

```
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:08:58:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s25
       valid_lft 81865sec preferred_lft 81865sec
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:cff:f4b1:8ace:8064/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 43189sec preferred_lft 26989sec
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 43189sec preferred_lft 26989sec
    inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:bf:e7:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.38.166/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link noprefixroute ens2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:287b:327f:9773:771f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 43189sec preferred_lft 26989sec
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:21b:21ff:febf:e728/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 43189sec preferred_lft 26989sec
    inet6 fe80::21b:21ff:febf:e728/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When I login I get

```
  IPv4 address for enp0s25: 192.168.1.8
  IPv6 address for enp0s25: 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:cff:f4b1:8ace:8064
  IPv6 address for enp0s25: 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:223:24ff:fe08:581f
  IPv4 address for ens2:    169.254.38.166
  IPv6 address for ens2:    2604:99c0:8:2fe6:287b:327f:9773:771f
  IPv6 address for ens2:    2604:99c0:8:2fe6:21b:21ff:febf:e728
```

New `ip address`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:08:58:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.8/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s25
       valid_lft 86396sec preferred_lft 86396sec
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:cff:f4b1:8ace:8064/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 43197sec preferred_lft 26997sec
    inet6 2604:99c0:8:2fe6:223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 43197sec preferred_lft 26997sec
    inet6 fe80::223:24ff:fe08:581f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:bf:e7:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::21b:21ff:febf:e728/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: And all of your IPv6 addresses posted there are timing out. I guess you have a firewall in your IMU-supplied equipment which is blocking the incoming connections.

Comment: The firewall on the router and my computer are off, and my computer is in the DMZ and has port forwarding set up to it

Comment: And application forwarding

Comment: DMZ and port forwarding are irrelevant and not used in IPv6. What model of router is it? It probably has some bizarro setting that needs to be looked up.

Comment: 844G-1 is the model Sorry I made a mistake, it is 844G-1 not 8446-1

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in this router's setup that would cause this. If you really have the firewall set to Security Off and stealth mode disabled, then it should be working. The other possibility is that IMU themselves have blocked incoming HTTP traffic to your device. This would be out of your control and you would have to speak to them about it.

Comment: When I did they said that they do not block anything but to be sure I am asking agian

Comment: The rouder IP is 2604:99c0:7:1224:fffe:ac7d:f5a4:101b/64 if that helps

Comment: Well, OK, the traceroute is probably a red herring. I can ping your router address but not any of your computer's addresses. They all time out. That suggests you still have a firewall problem within the router itself.

Comment: What do I need to look at to fix it?

Comment: As I said above: "If you really have the firewall set to Security Off and stealth mode disabled, then it should be working."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is obtaining both SLAAC and temporary privacy addresses from your router. The SLAAC address is fixed and based on the MAC address of your network card. This is what you will use for incoming connections.

The privacy addresses are preferentially used for *outgoing* connections, so that they are not associated with your incoming connections, or with each other when your computer gets a new one every 6-12 hours.

The privacy address is the one identified as `temporary` in your `ip addr` output, while the fixed SLAAC address is the other one, containing the `ff:fe` in the middle of the host part. Despite saying it's `dynamic` it will not actually change unless you replace the NIC or fake its MAC address.

---

Note that your router still has a firewall problem affecting your incoming connections, and since the obvious stuff doesn't seem to have helped, you may need to seek assistance with it from IMU.

Comment: What do I need to tell them?

Comment: You need to understand what we have discussed here, and tell them that. Your router is not allowing incoming IPv6 traffic. You can also point them at this post where they can see the whole discussion, but that may or may not be helpful until you can get past the script readers and to second level support.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I will do that now

Comment: Update: They said that they will have to do a "master reset" on my router